# Choosing the optimal index for SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I'm doing some problem sets in my database management course and I can't figure this specific problem out.

We have the following relation:

```
Emp (id, name, age, sal, ...)
```

And the following query:

```
SELECT id
FROM Emp
WHERE age > (select max(sal) from Emp);
```

We are then supposed to choose an index that we would be a good query optimizer. My answer would be to just use `Emp(age)` but the solution to the question is

```
Emp(age)
```

&

```
Emp(sal)
```

How come there are 2 indices? I can't seem to wrap my head around why you would need more than the age attribute..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you realize that the query is non-sensical, comparing `age` to `sal` (which is presumably a salary).  That said, two indexes are appropriate for:

```
SELECT e.id
FROM Emp e
WHERE e.age > (select max(e2.sal) from Emp e2);
```

I added table aliases to emphasize that the query is referring to the `Emp` table twice.

To get the maximum `sal` from the table, you want an index on `emp(sal)`.  The maximum is a simple index lookup operation.

Then you want to compare this to `age`.  Well, for a comparison to `age`, you want an index on `emp(age)`.  This an entirely separate reference to `emp` that has no reference to `sal`, so you cannot put the two columns in a single index.

The index on `age` may not be necessary.  The query may be returning lots of rows -- and tables that returns lots of rows don't generally benefit from a secondary index.  The one case where it can benefit from the index is if `age` is a *clustered* index (that is, typically the first column in the primary key).  However, I wouldn't recommend such an indexing structure.

Answer (score 1):

you need both indexes to get optimal performance

1) the subquery (select max(sal) from Emp) will benefit from indexing Emp(sal) because on a tree-index, retrieving the max would be much quicker

2) the outer query needs to run a filtering on Emp(age), so that also benefits from a tree-index

Comment: So if two subqueries would benefit from tree-index, we always split it into different index?

Comment: @FrederikJorgensen these two indices are operating independently, we don't need a compound index of both field. If there is some criteria that are some conditional dependence on Emp(sal) from Emp(age), then we can do some compound indexing